# generating an sequential five digit alphanumerical ID

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm

#### General Overview:

The function below spits out a random ID.  I'm using this to provide a confirmation alias to identify a record.  However, I've had to check for collision(however unlikely), because we are only using a five digit length.  With the allowed characters listed below, it comes out to about 33 million plus combinations.  Eventually we will get to five million or so records so collision becomes an issue.

#### The Problem:

Checking for dupe aliases is inefficient and resource heavy.  Five million records is a lot to search through.  Especially when this search is being conducted concurrently by different users.

#### My Question:

Is there a way to 'auto increment' the combinations allowed by this function?  Meaning I only have to search for the last record's alias and move on to the next combination?

#### Acknowledged Limitations:

I realize the code would be vastly different than the function below.  I also realize that mysql has an auto increment feature for numerical IDs, but the project is requiring a five digit alias with the allowed characters of '23456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ'.  My hands are tied on that issue.

#### My Current Function:

```
 public function random_id_gen($length)
 {
     $characters = '23456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ';
     $max = strlen($characters) - 1;
     $string = '';

     for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
         $string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, $max)];
     }

     return $string;
 }
```

Comment: +1 for a well structured question :)

Comment: Ha, thanks pendo.  The SO community is awesome.  It's disrespectful to slap up a sloppy question.

Comment: 32^5 = 33,554,432 < 50,000,000

Comment: It sounds like the ID does not need to be random, just unique.  Is that correct?

Comment: Is there any particular reason it has to be random? As opposed to `2`,`3`,..`Y`,`Z`,`22`..`2Z`...

Comment: create a separate table with the unique ids and mark which ones are used ( that's how we solved it )

Comment: Yes, it just has to be unique, but must be five digits even for the first ID issued

Comment: @gumbo, you're right.  I changed it.

Comment: With 30 million possible values, collision would become an issue around 10 thousand records (see [birthday problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)).

Comment: Tgr, I believe that would be true if we had said "what is the likely hood that two aliases already in the database are the same".  However, since we are naming an alias and saying "what's the likely hood that alias x resides in the database" the birthday problem doesn't apply.  
For example, if you were to say "how probable is it that two people have the birthday of 04/01 in a given group" that isn't the same as saying "how probable is it that two people have the same birthday in a given group".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just create a unique index on the alias column?

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uniq_alias ON MyTable(alias);
```

at which point you can try your insert/update and if it returns an error, generate a new alias and try again.

Comment: To quote Clay Davis: "shiiiiiiiiiiiiit".  Thank you sir I think this is the simplest solution.  That's the over the shoulder effect for you.

Answer (score 1):

What you really need to do is convert from base 10 to base `strlen($characters)`.

PHP comes with a built in `base_convert` function, but it doesn't do exactly what you want as it will use the numbers zero, one and the letter 'o', which you don't have in your version.  So you'll need a function to map the values from `base_convert` from/to your values:

```
function map_basing($number, $from_characters, $to_characters) {
    if ( strlen($from_characters) != strlen($to_characters)) {
       // ERROR!
    }

    $mapped = '';
    foreach( $ch in $number ) {
       $pos = strpos($from_characters, $ch);
       if ( $pos !== false ) {
          $mapped .= $to_characters[$pos];
       } else {
          // ERROR!
       }
    }

    return $mapped;
}
```

Now that you have that:

```
 public function next_id($last_id)
 {
    $my_characters = '23456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $std_characters ='0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv';

    // Map from your basing to the standard basing.
    $mapped = map_basing($last_id, $my_characters, $std_characters);

    // Convert to base 10 integer and increment.
    $intval = base_convert($mapped, strlen($my_characters), 10);
    $intval++;

    // Convert to standard basing, then to our custom basing.
    $newval_std = base_convert($intval, 10, strlen($my_characters));
    $newval = map_basing($newval_std, $std_characters, $my_characters);


    return $newval;
 }
```

Might be some syntax errors in there, but you should get the gist of it.

Answer (score 0):

You could roll your own auto-increment.  It would probably be fairly inefficient though as you'd have to figure out where in the process your increment was.  For instance, if you assigned the position in your random string as an integer and started with (0)(0)(0)(0)(0) that would equate to 22222 as the ID.  Then to get the next one, just increment the last value to (0)(0)(0)(0)(1) which would translate into 22223.  If the last one gets to your string length, then make it 0 and increment the second to last, etc...  It's not exactly random, but it would be incremented and unique.