# MySql table with not sequential id

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to create a table in MySql that it has an automatic ID field, but the ID is not sequential.  For example,  a random or pseudo random ID.
I have found solutions that suggest generating an ID and try to insert it until an unused ID is found ([generating an sequential five digit alphanumerical ID](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6335633/443685)). 
but nothing that can be done directly in the table definition, or a simpler trick.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

MySQL has a native function [`UUID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid) which will generate a globally unique identifier:

```
mysql> SELECT UUID();
    -> '6ccd780c-baba-1026-9564-0040f4311e29'
```

You can store its output in a `CHAR(36)` column.

```
INSERT INTO table (`uuid`, `col1`, `col2`) VALUES (UUID(), 'someval', 'someval');
```

According to the documentation though,

> Although UUID() values are intended to be unique, they are not necessarily unguessable or unpredictable. If unpredictability is required, UUID values should be generated some other way.

**Addendum** Another option is [`UUID_SHORT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid-short) for a 64-bit `unsigned INT` rather than a character field.

```
mysql> SELECT UUID_SHORT();
    -> 92395783831158784
```

Comment: Just a note - UUID_SHORT() actually produces sequential integers, so it is not suitable if you need non-sequential identifiers.

Answer (score 3):

Since you asked for a trick, you could use a common auto_incremented id and "fake" it by multiplying with a big prime (and then modulo 2^32):

```
CREATE TABLE AutoIncPrime
(id int unsigned auto_increment primary key
) ;
```

Insert values, from 1 to 10:

```
INSERT INTO AutoIncPrime 
VALUES (),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),() ;

SELECT * FROM AutoIncPrime ;
```

Output:

```
id
---
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8
 9
10
```

Fake the `id`, with a View:

```
CREATE VIEW AutoIncPrime_v AS
    SELECT 
        ((id*1798672429 ) & 0xFFFFFFFF) 
          AS FakeUUID
    FROM AutoIncPrime ;
```

Lets see our *"UUIDs"*:

```
  SELECT * FROM AutoIncPrime_v ;
```

Output:

```
FakeUUID
----------
1798672429
3597344858
1101049991
2899722420
 403427553
2202099982
4000772411
1504477544
3303149973
 806855106
```

You could even make it look more random with (more complicated bit mixing):

```
CREATE VIEW AutoIncPrime_v2 AS
    SELECT
        (   (((id*1798672429 ) & 0x55555555) << 1) 
          | (((id*1798672429 ) & 0xAAAAAAAA) >> 1)
        )
        AS FakeUUID
    FROM AutoIncPrime ;

SELECT * FROM AutoIncPrime_v2 ;

FakeUUID
----------
2537185310
3918991525
2186309707
1558806648
 604496082
1132630541
3719950903
2791064212
3369149034
 808145601
```

The trick is that you still have a sequential id in the table - which you can use to join to other tables. You just don't show it to the users - but only show the fake one.

If the table is to get big and the calculations slow, you can add another column in the table and store the FakeUUID value there with an INSERT trigger.

Comment: great!!! I have think about this method, but with worst functions (more complex and not mysql), so you give me a pointer. But a) I can't see the reverse way to the true ID (without inserting it with a trigger as you said) can you please post the reverse of this lovely functions? and b) what about uniqueness of the generated IDs (in a given range, of course)? I can´t figure what is this range for this functions, related to the selected mask and prime. realy thanks, and excuse my english

Comment: I will try to write the reverse functions tonight. Uniqueness is guaranteed, if you use a prime, like `1798672429` :)

Comment: Why not use `sha1()` instead of creating your own hash?

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann for fun? I probably didn't mean for this to be used in a serious/production environment anyway. Mind that the answer is 8 years old!

Answer (score 2):

Would a composite key work? A regular standard auto_increment field. You insert your new record, retrieve its new ID, then hash that ID with a salt, and update the record with that hash value.

If you do this all within a transaction, the in-progress version of the record without the hash will never be visible until the hash is generated. And assuming you've done proper salting, the resulting hash value will be for all intents and purposes 'random'.

Note that you can't do this in a single step, as the value of last_insert_id() in mysql is not updated with the new id until the record is actually written. The value retrieved during the actual insert parseing stage would be whatever id was inserted BEFORE this one.

Answer (score 1):

The only automatically generated default in the table definition allowed would be autoincrement ([MySQL Guide](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-defaults.html)).

You should be able to [write a trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-trigger.html) to automate this process though, maybe through the UUID function as Michael suggested.

Comment: from the first comment of your link CREATE TRIGGER sdata_insert BEFORE INSERT ON sometable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET NEW.guid = UUID();
END